Are SQLite triggers get invoked after connection is closed?
I would like to know what would happen in the following scenario.
Let’s say we have phones_tbl
and I define “AFTER UPDATE”
trigger that validates the phone number and abort the transaction if it’s not valid.
If the application shut down right after updating phones_tbl
(meaning the connection gets closed) , what would happen?
I tried to find relevant documentation

If your process exits before finishing the update statement, the transaction encompassing it will be rolled back and lost.
